# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've just installed `tensorflow-gpu` (1.0) with pip on a new system (after installing cuda and cudnn, obviously).

Unfortunately, my code (working well on cpu with tensorflow 0.12), now throws

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn'
```

When trying to call `tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`.
Moreover, the function is present in `/path/to/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn.py` and seems to be imported in `.../tensorflow/contrib/rnn/__init__.py`.

Any ideas ?

P.S.: Downgrade to 0.12 (`pip install tensorflow-gpu==0.12`) resolve my issue, but that a bit disappointing :/

Comment: Looking at the code at `HEAD` it should be there. Can you try with the latest version?

Comment: @drpng I've done a fresh install few hours ago and should have the latest version actually, but I'll get access to my workstation tomorrow, try to upgrade the package and keep you updated ;) Thanks !

Comment: @drpng I've just reinstalled it, still doesn't work :/

Comment: What happens when you `print(tf.contrib.rnn)`?

Comment: @drpng `<module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/__init__.py'>`

Comment: Apologies, I meant `print(dir(tf.contrib.rnn))`.

Comment: @drpng `['AttentionCellWrapper', 'BasicLSTMCell', 'BasicRNNCell', 'CoupledInputForgetGateLSTMCell', 'DropoutWrapper', 'EmbeddingWrapper', 'FusedRNNCell', 'FusedRNNCellAdaptor', 'GRUBlockCell', 'GRUCell', 'GridLSTMCell', 'InputProjectionWrapper', 'LSTMBlockCell', 'LSTMBlockFusedCell', 'LSTMBlockWrapper', 'LSTMCell', 'LSTMStateTuple',`

Comment: `'LayerNormBasicLSTMCell', 'MultiRNNCell', 'OutputProjectionWrapper', 'RNNCell', 'TimeFreqLSTMCell', 'TimeReversedFusedRNN', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'core_rnn_cell', 'static_bidirectional_rnn', 'static_rnn', 'static_state_saving_rnn']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that's an error in the tensorflow code. Sorry about that. Please add an entry here listing `@@stack_bidirectional_rnn` [here](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/__init__.py#L49) so that `stack_bidirectional_rnn` is exposed. Fix coming up. Feel free to open a github issue on our page and CC drpng there if you want to track progress.

Comment: I already have posted a issue on github, gonna links this answer there ;) Thanks !